# How would I compile Kiss_fft to use the double data type C++?

Tags: c++, fft, kissfft

I am looking to compile KISS_FFT (Keep it simple stupid) so that it can accept an array of double as input and output an array of doubles.

KISS_FFT is a library which does a fast Fourier Transformation on a set of data and outputs the result.  By default it looks like it uses the float data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to define the makefile variable `DATATYPE`, e.g.:

```
make DATATYPE=double ...
```

This in turn defines the macro `kiss_fft_scalar` as `double`.

To see this in action:

```
cd test
make DATATYPE=double test
```